# Choose Android Service with same action

Tags: android, android-service, android-intent-chooser

We created two applications as a service. Both runs without problems when we start the service implicit from a third application. But we want the user to chooose which service should be started.
Is there any way to create an AppChooser or something similar?

We added an activity to both services with an action to show the applications to the user. Is there any way to catch the clicked application, so we could start the service implicit?

Comment: You can define an identifier for each service, identifier like intent extra or something.